# Why I have this error message on starting Eclipse on MacOs

Tags: eclipse, osx-leopard

I try to use Eclipse Java EE on MacOS 10.5.8 but when I launch the IDE, I receive this error :

```
The JVM shared library "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.
```

In console mode, If I run java -version,the result is :

```
java version "1.5.0_28"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_28-b04-382-9M3326)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_28-157, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it is not due to Eclipse but to Java on Mac OS. I upgraded to Java Update 9 and it is working fine now.